# How to move an element within a structure, possibly with zippers?

Tags: data-structures, clojure, zipper

I have this structure:

```
 [{"a" {"b" 1 "c" 2} 
   "children" [{"a" {"b" 3 "c" 4} "children" []}]}
  {"a" {"b" 5 "c" 6} "children" []}
  {"a" {"b" 7 "c" 8}
    "children" [{"a" {"b" 9 "c" 10} "children" []} {"a" {"b" 10 "c" 10} "children" []}]}]
```

I'm trying to write an algorithm to move and element within a vector. For example in the last element, it has `children` vector with:

```
"children" [{"a" {"b" 9 "c" 10} "children" []} {"a" {"b" 10 "c" 10} "children" []}]
```

My function is supposed to search for a specific nested map - let's say, find the map where it is the value `10` for its `b` property. I will locate `{"a" {"b" 10 "c" 10} "children" []}`. Once I found it, I need to change its location with the vector. Let's assume, that `children` will become:

```
 "children" [{"a" {"b" 10 "c" 10} "children" []} {"a" {"b" 9 "c" 10} "children" []}]
```

With Zipper, I was able to traverse and locate the nested map but not sure how to move it within the vector.

Here is how my zipper is created:

```
  (z/zipper #(contains? % "children") #(get % "children")  (fn [_ c] c) data-structure)
```

Comment: It might help if you put the branch, children, and make-node fn's you are using.

Comment: @RedDeckWins What do you mean? Would you please explain?

Comment: To create a zipper, you need to provide three functions to operate on your data structure.  It is explained pretty clearly in the documentation for zipper.

Comment: @RedDeckWins I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what I want:

```
(defn update-tree [editable? edit loc]
  (loop [loc loc]
    (if (z/end? loc)
    (z/root loc)
    (if (editable? (z/node loc))
      (recur (-> loc z/up (z/edit edit) z/up z/next))
      (recur (z/next loc))))))
```

But it is only working for this exact structure. Nesting more elements is breaking the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution using [specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter):

```
  (def z [
          {"a" {"b" 1 "c" 2}
           "children" [{"a" {"b" 3 "c" 4}
                        "children" []}]}
          {"a" {"b" 5 "c" 6}
           "children" []}
          {"a" {"b" 7 "c" 8}
           "children" [{"a" {"b" 9 "c" 10}
                        "children" []}
                       {"a" {"b" 10 "c" 10}
                        "children" []}]}])


    (transform
      (walker (fn [x]
                (and
                  (vector? x)
                  (some
                    #(= 10
                        (get-in % ["a" "b"]))
                    x))))
      reverse
      z)
```

Returns:

```
[{"a" {"b" 1, "c" 2}, "children" [{"a" {"b" 3, "c" 4}, "children" []}]}
 {"a" {"b" 5, "c" 6}, "children" []}
 {"a" {"b" 7, "c" 8},
  "children"
  ({"a" {"b" 10, "c" 10}, "children" []}
   {"a" {"b" 9, "c" 10}, "children" []})}]
```

Notes:

1. The walker keeps walking, so if you're looking for a once-only transformation you should adapt this somehow. I tried adding `FIRST` to the transform vector but it still keeps walking even after finding one of the "b"s.
2. I tried using `collect-one` instead of the `get-in` but I did not succeed.

Feel free to edit it if you find a nicer solution. I'm still new to specter.

Comment: That is indeed beautiful. Nathan Marz is blowing my mind every time ! Thanks a lot for this answer. I'm still interested about doing it with Zippers. If nothing happened, I'm choosing your answer.

Comment: I agree, I think the zipper should be the #1 answer  since that's what they're for and it's pure clojure. I also think this solution is roughly ~2x slower than `zip/edit`.

Comment: I added an answer in case you want to have a look.

Comment: Looks good. You should accept that answer. Though I prefer fully self contained examples (so with example input, output and all definitions).

Comment: Actually it is not an answer. It is a broken algorithm. Your answer is still working as charm for more nested structures.